# Distribution-like linear form on distributions

Tags: functions, distribution-theory

Distributions (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))) extend the definition of functions.

They were introduced to me as a linear form on locally integrable functions, and one could say that they're interesting because that linear form includes functions (i.e. to any $L^1_{loc}$ function we can associate a distribution), but the reverse isn't true (there isn't a bijection), so that we indeed can say that we've created a generalization of functions.

Therefore I was wondering, **is there a linear form on distributions that is the equivalent of what distributions are to functions** ? A kind of "distributions on distributions" ? If so, do they hold any mathematical interest ?

Comment: What do you mean? to make the dual of the distribution spaces?

Comment: @Andrew If that yields interesting results, why not. If not, any other process that would be "like what distributions are to functions" would be great

Comment: Obviously $C_c^\infty \subseteq \mathcal D''$. The question is whether equality holds.